# Find number of tasks blocking on a POSIX semaphore

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, semaphore

Is there any way by which I can know the number of processes or threads waiting on a particular semaphore? 
Like a API to check the value. Sem_getvalue() only returns 0 and not a negative number whose absolute value is the number of tasks blocking on the semaphore as mentioned on a few sites.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I read that but Is there any other way to find that out or Linux just does not allow to find the count?

Comment: You want something like "`number_of_waiters_that_will_probably_be_obsolete_and_wrong_and_irrelevant_before_you_can_use_it = getNumberOfWaiters(semaphore);`"?

Answer (score 1):

I really have acquired a dislike for POSIX semaphores.  They lack a lot of the functionality available with SYS V semaphores.

If you are using SYS V semaphores, you can get various information using the semctl function:

```
int semctl(int semid, int semnum, int cmd, ...);
```

For example, to get the number of processed awaiting the defined semaphore to become zero:

```
int cnt = semtcl(my_semid, 0, GETZCNT);
```

That simple!

Long live SYS V semaphores!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the POSIX API other than `sem_getvalue`, which semantics, as you have seen, are optional.

That said, Linux implements *named* POSIX semaphores as files under `/dev/shm`, and thus a utility like [`fuser(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) can show you which processs have the file open.

If that doesn't work for you, you could implement a bookkeeping semaphore yourself with a POSIX mutex, a POSIX condition variable, and some space to record the semaphore value and any waiters.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could have taken a global **atomic_t** variable and incremented it before calling **sem_wait** and decremented in case you get the semaphore.